# Integration of Fortran code with Java by JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, fortran, gfortran

I have a problem with the integration of Fortran code with Java by JNI.
The problem probably occurs when I link the C object with the Fortran object.

File: HelloWorld.java

```
public class HelloWorld {
    native void foo();
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("test");
    }
    static public void main(String argv[]) {
        new HelloWorld().foo();
    }
}
```

File: ctest.c

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern void bar_();

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_foo
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject jobj)
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

Compilation:

```
$ gcc -fPIC -shared -lc \
    -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/include \
    -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/include/linux \
    -o libtest.so ctest.c
$ javac HelloWorld.java
$ java HelloWorld
Hello World!
```

Excellent, `Hello World!` works properly. 
But when I add Fortran code, Java throws an exception.

File: ftest.f95

```
subroutine bar()
    return
end
```

Compilation:

```
$ gcc -fPIC -shared -lc \
    -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/include \
    -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/include/linux \
    -o ctest.o ctest.c
$ gfortran -c ftest.f95
$ gcc -shared ftest.o ctest.o -o libtest.so
$ javac HelloWorld.java
$ java HelloWorld
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: HelloWorld.foo()V
        at HelloWorld.foo(Native Method)
        at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:7)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the `HelloWorld.java` exactly same in both compilation?

Comment: Yes, `HelloWorld.java` is exactly same.

Comment: You might consider using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna), which lets you map Java code directly onto a FORTRAN shared library without any additional native code compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things:

- For the build of the C object, you should not specify `-shared`. You are not generating an independent library. Instead, use `-c` to compile the object:

```
gcc -fPIC -lc \
    -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/include \
    -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/include/linux \
    -o ctest.o -c ctest.c
```

- If you want to link together the C and Fortran objects, you need to specify `-fPIC` in both cases and when linking the library. Furthermore, you need to link against `libgfortran`:

```
gfortran -fPIC -c ftest.f95
gcc -fPIC -shared ftest.o ctest.o -o libtest.so -lgfortran
```

- You need to extend the `java.library.path` such that the JVM can find the library:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
java -Djava.library.path="$PWD" HelloWorld
```

With these commands, your code runs fine on my machine.

Comment: `gfortran -fPIC -shared ftest.o ctest.o -o libtest.so` might work too and is slightly simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I found, the solution is `ld`.

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -lc \
    -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/include \
    -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/include/linux \
    -o ctest.o ctest.c
gfortran -c ftest.f95
ld -shared ftest.o ctest.o -o libtest.so -lc
```